# My surface pro 2 keyboard behave strangely

Tags: microsoft-surface-pro

If I press shift and 2, I expect @ sign to show up. It shows up " instead. To show @ I got to press shift and '.

Also pressing shift and 3 shows a poundsterling sign instead of #.

I wonder what's wrong.

Comment: That would happen if the keyboard was set to English (United Kingdom) , for example.

Comment: and how to set things differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instructions for Windows 10

Go to Settings and select time and language
[image]

Click on display language

[image]

Click Options

[image]

Click on Add a Keyboard and select the appropriate layout for your keyboard, for example US.

You can choose which layout to use from the Taskbar Notification area.

[image]

Comment: That's a good answer. I did that before asking this question. Perhaps I didn't restart?

Comment: You shouldn't need to.