# Wrong display according to keyboard on a laptop

Tags: display, keyboard

I am using Lenovo laptop. On its key board in number section, there is " written above number 2 but when I press shift +2 I got @. There are also similar problems when using symbols 
Is it a fault in the laptop and how it can be corrected
Regard

Comment: What Operating System are you using? The laptop has a UK keyboard layout but the OS is set to US keyboard layout. Here are instructions to change keyboard layout for Windows 10 http://superuser.com/questions/1082521/my-surface-pro-2-keyboard-behave-strangely/1082749#1082749

Comment: Thanks for your response
I will check your suggestion and get back soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a normal US/English keyboard @ is "above" 2. My guess is the laptop was designed to be used in a part of the world where there are more symbols/letters than the regular English alphabet. A perfect example of this is Quebec (Canada), where the keyboard has many other symbols that can be accessed through special key combinations. 
I believe you can switch your particular keyboard to work as intended by changing the OS/system language to whatever language the laptop is set to use.

Answer (score 2):

This i caused by wrong language and keyboard settings, to fix it go to control panel -> Language and region  click on add a language and choose English(US), then set your new input as a default

Comment: Thanks for your response
I will check your suggestion and get back soon